# Scheduling Login, post request and logout in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have Test Plan in Jmeter having following three sections:

1. Login (HTTP Sampler)
2. Runtime Controller (Containing HTTP POST Requests)
3. Logout (HTTP Sampler)

I want to schedule the test in following way:

1. 300 users LOGIN
2. Once all the users are logged in, the Runtime Controller runs for 1 hour posting HTTP Post request
3. All the 300 users logout.

I have set the Thread group to 300 users, and Runtime controller duration to 3600 seconds. But I have observed that the Login, POST requests and Logout are not synchronized the way I want it to be.

I am new to Jmeter, please help!

Comment: What error you are getting??

Comment: The Users Logout and after that al the requests through 401 unauthorized error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **Synchronizing Timer** to achieve 300 users doing same activity concurrently.

Synchronizing timer blocks or holds the threads at a point till x no. of threads are blocked. It then releases all blocked threads at once so that peak concurrent load (300 users doing post activity at a time) is achieved.

you should follow below sequence,

[image]

Please change Number of Simulated Users to group by to 300 i.e your needed users.